# Duplicate question

Tags: support, duplicate

I believe I asked a dup because my problem didn't solve at first. Now that I solved my problem, you might want to put together my question as a duplicate of the first question.

[Enable history for shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388399/enable-history-for-shell)

[How to enable ksh command history between sessions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386319/how-to-enable-ksh-command-history-between-sessions/386344#386344)